# cakephp table and entities

Tags: php, inheritance, cakephp

I am doing a **Quick start guide on cakephp**. When i visit the URL http://localhost:8765/articles/index . An error shows up saying 'Unknown method "addBehaviour"'. The source code for the **ArticlesTable.php** file is below.

```
<?php

namespace App\Model\Table;

use Cake\ORM\Table;
class ArticlesTable extends Table{

    public function initialize(array $config){
        $this->addBehaviour('Timestamp');
    }

    public function beforeSave($event, $entity, $options){
        if($entity->isNew() && !$entity->slug){
            $sluggedTitle = Text::slug($entity->title);
            //trim slug to maximum length defined in schema
            $entity->slug = substr($sluggedTitle, 0, 191);

        }
    }
}
```

This is happening after i added this code

```
public function beforeSave($event, $entity, $options){
        if($entity->isNew() && !$entity->slug){
            $sluggedTitle = Text::slug($entity->title);
            //trim slug to maximum length defined in schema
            $entity->slug = substr($sluggedTitle, 0, 191);

        }
```

Before adding this code it seems like the **ArticlesTable.php** was not in use because i removed it and everything worked correctly like before. The issue is that i want tHE **ArticlesTable.php** file to work. I think the problem might be related to **inheritance**. I have been doing **java** and **c++** and this is why i think the problem is linked to **inheritance**.

Comment: There is no such method as `Model::addBehaviour()`. What you should use is `Model::addBehavior()`.

Comment: It think there is a typo. Use  $this->addBehavior('Timestamp');

Comment: Thanks a lot @Szymon